# How can I debug a child_process fork process from visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, child-process

## Description

Executing `child_process.fork` from a vscode debug process fails to run with and returns exit code 12. Running the same test from a terminal session succeeds.

### Sample Mocha Unit Test

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { fork } from 'child_process';
import path from 'path';

describe('Child Process Fork', () => {
  it('Successfully Forks A Simple Process', (done) => {
    const child = fork(path.join(__dirname, 'SimplyExit.js'), [], { stdio: 'pipe' });
    child.on('exit', (data) => {
      expect(data).to.equal(0);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

### SimplyExit.js

```
process.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executing `child_process.fork` from a parent node process that was started with an `inspect-brk` option active will cause this error if you don't manually specify a different `inspect-brk` port or remove the option.

[Here's the line of code in the node.js source that causes this to happen](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b505d2a1cf182d39e224e80a6fa4a179cd788655/lib/child_process.js#L82)

### Solution

Add `execArgv: []` to your fork options to prevent the child process from inheriting the `inspect-brk` option. Here's the full working code.

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { fork } from 'child_process';
import path from 'path';

describe('Child Process Fork', () => {
  it('Successfully Forks A Simple Process', (done) => {
    const child = fork(path.join(__dirname, 'SimplyExit.js'), [], { stdio: 'pipe', execArgv: [] });
    child.on('exit', (data) => {
      expect(data).to.equal(0);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thumbs up!